# Can linux-lowlatency be used with UEFI secure boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I am using the linux-lowlatency package as my main kernel (as the generic kernel produces horrible lags while playing audio to my bluetooth speakers).

I regularly find that my /boot partition is full, due partly to having the generic kernel installed alongside the low latency one. So I wanted to remove the linux-generic package, but I found that it will also remove the linux-signed-generic package.

linux-signed-generic is described as: "Signed with Ubuntu EFI key".

There is no linux-signed-lowlatency.

So here is my questions:

- **can I use the low latency kernel package with EFI secure boot ?**
- (is linux-lowlatency also signed with Ubuntu EFI key ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure boot will let the Microsoft signed shim.efi boot, which then runs the Canonical signed grubx64.efi.  Now this Canonical signed grub can run either signed or unsigned (by Canonical) Linux kernels -- some features will not be available on the unsigned kernels at boot, but you probably won't notice.  Last time I tried this was with the 12.10 kernels, so things may have changed.

Comment: In fact I now get a notice on boot saying "booting in insecure mode". I can't really tell if the message is from the Bios or from the grub, but your response makes me think it's a grub message...